# How to model a difference score for cross-sectional, hierarchical survey data

Tags: multilevel-analysis, latent-variable, differences

**What is the best way to model a difference score that is based on cross-sectional survey data, while also taking into account the hierarchical structure of the survey data?**

I have the following survey data: Survey respondents from 11 cities were asked how welcoming they perceive the members of their city to be of 1) Immigrants in general and 2) Immigrants who are not Christian. They provided an answer on a 7-point rating scale.

I would like to use these welcoming perceptions as the outcome variable and explore what demographic characteristics of the respondents predict these welcoming perceptions. At the same time, I would like to take into account the hierarchical structure of the survey data (respondents nested in the 11 cities). Approximately 400 respondents were surveyed in each city.

For the outcome variable, I was thinking of using a difference score (2-1). I have read that observed difference scores can be problematic because they assume that there is no measurement error. As an alternative, I have seen people use latent difference scores. However, most of the time these latent difference scores are used to model change across two time points. In my case, I have one time point only.

Would it be possible and make sense to model a latent difference score at the individual level which is then regressed on level 1 predictors (the demographic variables), while considering the cities as clusters? There would not be any level 2 predictors.

Alternatively, would it make sense to create a ratio score out of the welcoming perceptions (e.g., welcoming of immigrants who are not Christian divided by Immigrants in general), and use that as the outcome variable in a multi-level regression?

What would be the best course of action here, and why? Any advice and links to useful resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Difference scores, including latent difference scores, are used when you are measuring the same variable (or set of variables as in a scale) repeatedly. I have not seen them used for the purposes you describe here. Have you considered choosing one of the variables as an outcome and the other as the main predictor of interest?